# "cannot be cast to" error raising

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

I'm working in struts-config 1.2 application. In my struts-config, I have declaration entry for a form and I used this form for some actions. I compiled this objects first with java 1.4 version. That time it was working fine. Now I modified as java version 1.6. I compiled all the objects. Now it is throwing error as my form class cannot be cast to my extend java class. I dont know this is may be due to version change.

Please give me a solution for this, I am struggling with this for 2 days.

My struct-config code is:

```
<form-bean name="xCustomerPortalForm" type="com.portal.form.XCustomerPortalForm" />
...
<action path="/editXPortalCustomerNew"
        type="com.xmportal.struts.X2AProcessBridgeAction"
        parameter=""
        name="xCustomerPortalForm"
        scope="request"
        validate="false">
  <forward name="success_en" path="/jsp/XMPortalCustomerRegistration.jsp" />
  <forward name="failure_en" path="/jsp/XMPortalCustomerRegistration.jsp" />
</action>
```

This is my error message:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.portal.form.XCustomerPortalForm cannot be cast to com.xmportal.struts.X2AFormBase
    at com.xmportal.struts.X2AProcessBridgeAction.exposeInScope(X2AProcessBridgeAction.java:205)
    at com.xmportal.struts.X2AProcessBridgeAction.checkDataSingle(X2AProcessBridgeAction.java:331)
    at com.xmportal.struts.X2AProcessBridgeAction.checkData(X2AProcessBridgeAction.java:361)
    at com.xmportal.struts.X2AProcessBridgeAction.checkOutcome(X2AProcessBridgeAction.java:618)
    at com.xmportal.struts.X2AProcessBridgeAction.executeLogic(X2AProcessBridgeAction.java:864)
    at org.apache.struts.scaffold.BaseHelperAction.executeLogic(Unknown Source)
    at com.xmportal.struts.X2AProcessBridgeAction.execute(X2AProcessBridgeAction.java:886)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
    ...
```

I am getting error in this object only in X2AProcessBridgeAction

```
 try {
            X2AFormBase passedForm = (X2AFormBase) form;
            String loginKeyVal= passedForm.getLoginKey();           
                passedForm.set(bean);
            } catch (Exception e) {             
                e.printStackTrace();            

            }
```

Comment: Show us the code, and the exact error message (with the stack trace if it's a runtime error). Without this information, it's impossible to help. Also, it's "struts", not "structs".

Comment: And also, the code of `com.xmportal.struts.X2AProcessBridgeAction.exposeInScope` (especially line 205, since that's the line the exception come from).

Comment: Show us the code of com.portal.form.XCustomerPortalForm and com.xmportal.struts.X2AFormBase. The first one should extend or implement the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple really,

In your `struts-config.xml`, your `action` (type `com.xmportal.struts.X2AProcessBridgeAction`) name is `xCustomerPortalForm` (which is typed to `com.portal.form.XCustomerPortalForm`). This means, when Struts (`ActionServlet`) will call your bean `com.xmportal.struts.X2AProcessBridgeAction` methods, the `ActionForm form` will **always** be of type `com.portal.form.XCustomerPortalForm`.

So, this typecasting will **always** fail as it's incompatible type:

```
X2AFormBase passedForm = (X2AFormBase) form;
```

Struts expects you to do this:

```
XCustomerPortalForm xCustomPortalForm = (XCustomerPortalForm)form;
```

I hope, this is clear. Your Action is mapped to only one Form Bean.

Answer (score 0):

Your form bean is configured to `XCustomerPortalForm`. In your `exposeInScope()` you are trying to cast the form to a `X2AFormBase`. Looks like you have one of two errors:

1. `XCustomerPortalForm` does not extend/implement `X2AFormBase`.
2. `XCustomerPortalForm` and `X2AFormBase` are loaded from different classloaders/jars, in which case you have different instances of the classes in the JVM.

Comment: i have checked my code, i have the extend as well as implemet for x2aformbase. And teir path also correct only. Is there any other possiblitiesare threr?

Comment: @Nagarajan are these classes present in the same jar and loaded by the same classloader?

Comment: Yes shams it is thr.. bcoz for the other forms the same process is working fine.

Comment: Try using reflection to print the class hierarchy and actually checking if X2AFormBase is in there for form. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/ClassReflectionnameforsuperclass.htm